# How was the Philosopher's Stone destroyed?

Tags: harry-potter, philosophers-stone

How was the Philosopher's Stone destroyed? Was it ever stated in the first book how the Stone was destroyed? Was the Stone destroyed when Harry dropped it?

Comment: Since it is not The One Ring(tm), I suppose you can simply smash it with an axe.

Comment: Or indeed a hammer. Bear in mind that very few real gems are immune to being smashed to powder by a hammer wielded by hand. Gems are usually hard, but brittle.

Comment: It probably involved [Edward Elric](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Edward_Elric) using it for... [something](https://www.vgcats.com/comics/?strip_id=168)

Answer (score 39):

### There is no in-universe answer. In addition, the Stone was *not* destroyed when Harry dropped it.

In the first book of the Harry Potter series, Dumbledore tells Harry that he will destroy the Stone. This prompts a discussion about how Nicolas Flamel will die as a result. But in the conversation, Dumbledore never tells Harry how it will be done. The narrator never explains either. Unfortunately, there's no answer to your question.

> ‘Not the Stone, boy, you — the effort involved nearly killed you.  For one terrible moment there, I was afraid it had. As for the Stone, it has been destroyed.’
>
> ‘Destroyed?’ said Harry blankly. ‘But your friend — Nicolas Flamel —’
>
> ‘Oh, you know about Nicolas?’ said Dumbledore, sounding quite delighted. ‘You *did* do the thing properly, didn't you? Well, Nicolas and I have had a little chat and agreed it's all for the best.’
>
> ‘But that means he and his wife will die, won't they?’
>
> ‘They have enough Elixir stored to set their affairs in order and then, yes, they will die.’
>
> <sup>[*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* (1997) - Chapter Seventeen: "The Man with Two Faces"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone)</sup>

Comment: Can you cite the passage where Dumbledore says this? The version I read has it differently.

Comment: Let me find it.

Comment: @Alex If the copy you read was in English, that could be due to differences between the original version written by Rowling and the US localized version. They changed a lot more than just idiomatics and spelling for the American release...

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn For example, they changed the formatting; double-quotes instead of single-quotes for text, and double-spaced paragraphs instead of single-spaced with first line of paragraph indented.